# The compare line doesn't work, why? How can I fix it?

Tags: java, error-handling

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] my_Numbers= {1789, 2035, 1899, 1456, 2013, 
            1458, 2458, 1254, 1472, 2365, 
            1456, 2165, 1457, 2456};
    for(int i=0; i < my_Numbers.length;){
        if (Integer.compare(my_Numbers[i],my_Numbers[(i+1)])==1) {
            int x = my_Numbers[i];
            my_Numbers[i] = my_Numbers[i+1];
            my_Numbers[i+1] = x;
            i=0;
        }else {i++;}
    }
    String  result= my_Numbers.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? That is not how you print an array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide on [ask] a good question. Also, Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself.** Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.

Comment: In addition to the problem you're reporting, `String  result= my_Numbers.toString();` won't do what you intend. You should use `Arrays.toString(myNumbers)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] my_Numbers= {1789, 2035, 1899, 1456, 2013,
            1458, 2458, 1254, 1472, 2365,
            1456, 2165, 1457, 2456};
    for(int i=0; i < my_Numbers.length-1;){
        if (Integer.compare(my_Numbers[i],my_Numbers[(i+1)])==1) {
            int x = my_Numbers[i];
            my_Numbers[i] = my_Numbers[i+1];
            my_Numbers[i+1] = x;
            i=0;
        }else {i++;}
    }
    String  result= Arrays.toString(my_Numbers);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score -1):

First of all add if condition before performing (i+1) because it will give you arrayindexoutof bound exception when i  will be last element.